# What is correct way from below

Tags: modal-verbs

"Would you please clear the table."

or

"Could you please clear the table."

From above which is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Could** you please clear the table?

You would use this if you are asking someone if they have time (or are not busy) to clear the table. It is polite neutral.

> **Would** you please clear the table?

Here you are asking someone as a favor. This would be considered polite.
Also you could use this where impatience for something to happen.

> I already asked you three times. **Would** you please clear the table?